# Extracting elements that are to the right of a certain name from each vector

Tags: r, loops

I have a list that consists of multiple named vectors.

```
[[1]]
N        VER    DET    N     RP   VER  ADJ
“She”  “met”   “a”   “man” "who" “is” “short”

[[2]]
N.      VER    DET    N     RP   VER     DET      N
“He”  “saw”   “a”  “woman” "who" “plays” “the”   “piano”
```

I am trying to extract elements that are to the right of a certain name, for example, RP (relative pronoun), from each vector.

In this case, the output should look like this:

```
[[1]]
 RP   VER  ADJ
"who" “is” “short”

[[2]]
 RP       VER     DET     NOUN
"who" “plays” “the”   “piano”
```

Note that RP may appear in a vector multiple times. I only need to extract elements that are to the right of the rightmost RP. Also, the list contains vectors with NA value.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. In your question you say "to the right of" but then in the example you include the "who".  To me that is "RP and to the right" ( as compared to "to the right of the RP).  Can you please clarify? Also, will there alway be an RP?  It also would be great if you would read about how to make a great reproducible example.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. As you say,  "RP and to the right" is correct. In addition, there won't always be RP in the named vectors. I am happy to edit the question if it is necessary/possible.

Comment: Please post the output of `dput`, e.g. `dput(mylist[c(1, 3, 4)])`, with 1, 3, 4 being the relevant vectors equivalent to a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (minimal reproducible example).

Answer (score 1):

If this is your data

```
lis
[[1]]
      N     VER     DET       N      RP     VER     ADJ 
  "She"   "met"     "a"   "man"   "who"    "is" "short" 

[[2]]
    N   VER   DET     N 
"She" "met"   "a" "man" 

[[3]]
     N.     VER      DD     DET       N      RP     VER     DET       N 
   "He"   "saw"   "who"     "a" "woman"   "who" "plays"   "the" "piano" 

[[4]]
     N.     VER      LL     DET       N      RP     VER     DET       N 
   "He"   "saw"      NA     "a" "woman"   "who" "plays"   "the" "piano"
```

Using `lapply`

```
lapply(lis, \(x){
  loc <- grep("who", x)
  if(any(loc)){x[max(loc):length(x)]} else {NA}})
```

output

```
[[1]]
     RP     VER     ADJ 
  "who"    "is" "short" 

[[2]]
[1] NA

[[3]]
     RP     VER     DET       N 
  "who" "plays"   "the" "piano" 

[[4]]
     RP     VER     DET       N 
  "who" "plays"   "the" "piano"
```

##### Data

```
lis <- list(c(N = "She", VER = "met", DET = "a", N = "man", RP = "who", 
VER = "is", ADJ = "short"), c(N = "She", VER = "met", DET = "a", 
N = "man"), c(N. = "He", VER = "saw", DD = "who", DET = "a", 
N = "woman", RP = "who", VER = "plays", DET = "the", N = "piano"
), c(N. = "He", VER = "saw", LL = NA, DET = "a", N = "woman", 
RP = "who", VER = "plays", DET = "the", N = "piano"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Function to truncate a character vector from a given string 
# to the end of the vector: truncate_vector_from_string => function
truncate_vector_from_string <- function(x, pattern, direction = c("before", "after"), inclusive = TRUE, match_case = TRUE){
  # Stop if vector is not a character vector: 
  stopifnot(is.character(x))
  # Stop if search character is not a character vector:
  stopifnot(is.character(pattern))
  # Stop if the inclusive and match_case arguments are not logicals:
  stopifnot(is.logical(inclusive) & is.logical(match_case))
  # Resolve whether or not to truncate the vector before or after 
  # the given point: direction_resolved => character vector
  direction_resolved <- match.arg(direction)
  # Compute the length of the vector: n => integer scalar
  n <- length(x)
  # Resolve the base index: base_idx => integer scalar
  base_idx <- which(grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = !match_case))
  # If there are no matches: 
  if(all(!base_idx)){
    # Set the resulting vector to NA
    res_vec <- NA_character_
  }else{
    # Compute the first occurence of the given scalar: 
    # idx => integer scalar
    if(inclusive){
      idx <- min(base_idx)
    }else{
      idx <- min(base_idx) + ifelse(direction_resolved == "before", -1, 1)
    }
    # If the idx is less than 1: 
    if(idx < 1){
      # Set the result to NA of type character:
      # res_vec => character vector
      res_vec <- NA_character_
    # Else if we want to go before the search string: 
    }else if(direction_resolved == "before"){
      # Resolve the new, truncated, vector: 
      # res_vec => character vector
      res_vec <- x[seq_len(idx)]
    }else{
      # Resolve the new, truncated, vector: 
      # res_vec => character vector
      res_vec <- x[idx:n]
    }
  }
  # Explicitly define the returned object:
  # character vector => env
  return(res_vec)
}

# String to find: find_str => character scalra
find_str <- "who"

# Truncate the list of vectors: 
# res_list => list of named vectors
res_list <- lapply(
  test_data,
  function(x){
    truncate_vector_from_string(x, find_str, "after", inclusive = TRUE)    
  }
)
```

Data:

```
# Data: test_data => list of named vectors
test_data <- lapply(
  list(
    list(
      N = "She",
      VER = "met",
      DET = "a",
      N = "man",
      RP = "who",
      VER = "is",
      ADJ = "short"
    ),
    list(
      N. = "He",
      Ver = "saw",
      DET = "a",
      N = "woman",
      RP = "who",
      VER = "plays",
      DET = "the",
      N = "piano"
    )
  ),
  unlist
)
```